# set RPM package name according to version using CMAKE/CPack

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, rpm, cpack

I want to generate RPM file and later progress the version using build machine.

What I want to do is to run `cpack -R "100.0.4d"` or similar fashion

In return get rpm file: `myapp-100.0.4d.rpm`.

This is to support automated version generation
to do so I constructed the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
PROJECT (myapp)
SET (APPLICATION_NAME "MYAPP")
SET (APPLICATION_CODENAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
SET (APPLICATION_COPYRIGHT_YEARS "2018")
SET (APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR "100")
SET (APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR "0")
SET (APPLICATION_VERSION_PATCH "1")
SET (APPLICATION_VERSION_TYPE DS1)
SET (APPLICATION_VERSION_STRING "${APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR}.${APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR}.${APPLICATION_VERSION_PATCH}-${APPLICATION_VERSION_TYPE}")

...
#
# CPack Generic
#

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "1")

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "myapp")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${APPLICATION_VERSION_MAJOR}.${APPLICATION_VERSION_MINOR}.${APPLICATION_VERSION_PATCH}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "my app servers")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "${APPLICATION_VENDOR_NAME}")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_URL "${APPLICATION_VENDOR_URL}")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE.md")
SET(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "RPM")
SET(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "x86_64")
SET(CPACK_RPM_COMPRESSION_TYPE "gzip")
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
```

Using `cpack -R` only sets the rpm package version but does not change the filename.

I tried using `cpack -D` to change `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_*` , `APPLICATION_VERSION_*` with no change.

How can it be achieved?